# Is there a way to identify install location for the previous version of the app in WiX?

Tags: wix

I am migrating the installation location of the app.
And I need to copy few files from the old location to the new one. The old location is not going to be deleted during uninstall so we are fine with that.
I plan to use C# CustomAction for that and I am able to identify if the certain version of the app is installed using:

```
<Upgrade Id="$(var.TOOLBOX_PRODUCT_UPGRADECODE)">
      <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Property="SELFFOUND"
                      Minimum="3.2.1" IncludeMinimum="yes"
                      Maximum="3.7.1" IncludeMaximum="yes" />
</Upgrade>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="LaunchReadme" After="InstallFinalize">VIEWRELEASENOTES = 1 and NOT Installed </Custom>
  <Custom Action="CopyFiles" After="InstallFinalize">SELFFOUND</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Id="CopyFiles" BinaryKey="CustomActions" Execute="immediate" DllEntry="ImmediateCopyCustomAction" />
```

The only thing I am missing is to be able to detect previous installation location. Is this possible to be done using Product Id?

Answer (score 0):

Detecting the previous installation location directly using the Product Id in a Custom Action is not straightforward because the Product Id doesn't store information about installation paths.

You can use the Windows Installer API to query for the property that stores the installation path of the application. Typically, this is the INSTALLLOCATION property, but it might be different depending on how your installer is set up.

**Use the Windows Installer API**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

public class CustomActions
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult FindPreviousInstallationPath(Session session)
    {
        try
        {
            string productCode = "your previous prod code goes hereYOUR_PREVIOUS_PRODUCT_CODE_HERE"; 
            string property = "InstallLocation"; 
            string installLocation = Registry.GetValue(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\" + productCode + @"\InstallProperties", "InstallLocation", null) as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(installLocation))
            {
                session.Log("Previous installation location found: " + installLocation);
                session["PREV_INSTALL_PATH"] = installLocation;
                return ActionResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                session.Log("Previous installation location not found.");
                return ActionResult.Failure;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            session.Log("Error finding previous installation location: " + ex.Message);
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }
    }
}
```

This example attempts to read the InstallLocation from the registry, which is a common place to store such information. Note that you need to adapt the productCode and possibly the property name to fit your specific application

Answer (score 0):

If you know a componentid from the previous product you can use AppSearch/CompLocator to resolve the location of an installed component.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/appsearch-table
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/complocator-table

for WiX that's...

https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/xsd/wix/property/

https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/xsd/wix/directorysearchref/

https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/xsd/wix/componentsearch/